# Error drawing images on canvas in kotlin android game

Tags: java, android, kotlin, game-development

I'm creating my first game using native kotlin, but I'm having difficulties.

I managed to set up the game loop and create the renderings, they work very well, but after a while with the game running, dragging begins to appear on the images drawn on the canvas.

I cannot identify what is causing this problem. Could someone help me understand?

Here are some code snippets:

##### Init variables

```
private var bitmapImage: Bitmap
var isRunning: Boolean = false
private val FPS: Int = (1000 / 60)
private val backgroundImage = BackgroundImage()
private var startTime: Long = 0
private var frameTime: Long = 0
private var velocity = 3
private var velocityFly = 0
private var fly: Fly
var obstacle: Obstacle
var numObstacle: Int = 3
var velocityObstacle: Int = 10
val minY = 250 // default 250
val maxY = ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT - minY - 500
val centerObstacles = ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH * 3 / 4
var listObstacle: ArrayList<Obstacle> = arrayListOf()
var random: Random = Random
var iObstacle = 0
var flyDie: FlyDie
var isDie = false
//var sound: SoundManager
var score = 0
var textPaint = Paint()
```

##### Thread run

```
    override fun run() {
    Log.w(TAG, "Running")
    bitmapImage = bitmapImage.also { scaleResize(it) }
    var count = 0
    while (isRunning) {
        count++
        startTime = System.nanoTime()

        val canvas = holder.lockCanvas()
        Log.w(TAG, "Canvas $canvas")
        if (canvas != null) {
            try {
                synchronized(holder) {
                    render(canvas)
                    renderFly(canvas)
                    renderObstacle(canvas)
                    renderFlyDie(canvas)
                    renderScore(canvas)
                }
            } finally {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
            }
        }

        frameTime = (System.nanoTime()) - startTime / 1000000
        if (frameTime < FPS) {
            Log.w(TAG, "FPS $FPS")
            try {
                sleep(FPS - frameTime)
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                Log.e("Interruped", "Threed sleep error")
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Score $score")

        Log.w(TAG, "Thread Finished")
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Game loop $count ");
}
```

##### Draw Canvas

```
    private fun createObstacle() {
    for (i in 0 until numObstacle) {
        val obstacle = Obstacle(resources)
        obstacle.x = ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH + centerObstacles * i
        obstacle.y = try {random.nextInt(maxY - minY) + minY} catch (e: Exception) { 250 }
        listObstacle.add(obstacle)
    }
}

private fun renderFlyDie(canvas: Canvas) {
    Log.w(TAG, "RenderFlyDie")
    if (isDie) {
        var i = flyDie.currentFrame

        canvas.drawBitmap(flyDie.getFlyDie(i), flyDie.x.toFloat(), flyDie.y.toFloat(), null)
        i++

        flyDie.currentFrame = i

        if (i == flyDie.maxFrame) {
            isRunning = false
        }
    }
}

private fun renderObstacle(canvas: Canvas?) {
    Log.w(TAG, "RenderObstacle")
    if (state == 1) {
        if (listObstacle[iObstacle].x < flyDie.x - obstacle.w) {
            iObstacle++
            if (iObstacle > numObstacle - 1) {
                iObstacle = 0
            }
            score++
        } else if (((listObstacle[iObstacle].x) < fly.x + fly.getFly(0).width) && (listObstacle.get(
                iObstacle
            ).y > fly.y || listObstacle[iObstacle].getBottomY() < fly.y + fly.getFly(0).height)
        ) {
            isDie = true
        }

        for (i in 0 until numObstacle) {
            if (listObstacle[i].x < -obstacle.w) {
                listObstacle[i].x = listObstacle[i].x + numObstacle * centerObstacles
                listObstacle[i].y = try { random.nextInt(maxY - minY) + minY } catch (e: Exception) { 250 }
            }

            listObstacle[i].x = listObstacle[i].x - velocityObstacle

            canvas?.let {
                Log.w(TAG, "Obstaculo ${listObstacle[i].randomNumber}")
                when (listObstacle[i].randomNumber) {
                    0 -> {
                        getObstacleToDrawTop(
                            it, i, obstacle.obstacleTop, listObstacle[i].getTopY().toFloat()
                        )
                        getObstacleToDrawBottom(it, i, obstacle.obstacleBottom)
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        getObstacleToDrawTop(
                            it,
                            i,
                            obstacle.obstacleTop2,
                            listObstacle[i].getTopY2().toFloat()
                        )
                        getObstacleToDrawBottom(it, i, obstacle.obstacleBottom2)
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        getObstacleToDrawTop(
                            it, i, obstacle.obstacleTop3, listObstacle[i].getTopY3().toFloat()
                        )
                        getObstacleToDrawBottom(it, i, obstacle.obstacleBottom3)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun getObstacleToDrawTop(
    canvas: Canvas, index: Int, bitmapImageTop: Bitmap, topImage: Float
) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(
        bitmapImageTop, listObstacle[index].x.toFloat(), topImage, null
    )
}

private fun getObstacleToDrawBottom(canvas: Canvas, index: Int, bitmapImageBottom: Bitmap) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(
        bitmapImageBottom,
        listObstacle[index].x.toFloat(),
        listObstacle[index].getBottomY().toFloat(),
        null
    )
}

private fun renderFly(canvas: Canvas) {
    Log.w(TAG, "RenderFly")
    if (state == 1) {
        if (!isDie) {
            if (fly.y < (ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT - fly.getFly(0).height) || velocityFly < 0) {
                velocityFly += 2
                fly.y = ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2//fly.y + velocityFly
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isDie) {
        var current = fly.currentFrame
        canvas.drawBitmap(fly.getFly(current), fly.x.toFloat(), fly.y.toFloat(), null)
        current++

        if (current > fly.maxFrame) {
            current = 0
        }

        fly.currentFrame = current
    }
}

private fun render(canvas: Canvas) {
    Log.w(TAG, "RenderBackground")
    backgroundImage.x = backgroundImage.x - velocity

    bitmapImage.also {

        if (backgroundImage.x < -it.width) {
            backgroundImage.x = 0
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(
            it, backgroundImage.x.toFloat(), backgroundImage.y.toFloat(), null
        )

        if (backgroundImage.x < -it.width - ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH) {
            bitmapImage.let {
                canvas.drawBitmap(
                    it,
                    (backgroundImage.x + it.width).toFloat(),
                    (backgroundImage.y + it.height).toFloat(),
                    null
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun renderScore(canvas: Canvas) {
    Log.w(TAG, "RenderScore")
    textPaint.color = Color.rgb(255, 165, 0)
    textPaint.textSize = 120.toFloat()
    textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT
    textPaint.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.baloo)
    canvas.drawText("Pontos: $score", 20F, 120.toFloat(), textPaint)
}
```

##### Surface Methods

```
private var playThread: PlayThread

init {
    val holder = holder
    holder.addCallback(this)
    isFocusable = true
    playThread = PlayThread(context, holder, resources)
}

override fun surfaceCreated(p0: SurfaceHolder) {
    if (playThread.isRunning.not()) {
        playThread = PlayThread(context, p0, resources)
    } else {
        playThread.start()
    }
}

override fun surfaceChanged(p0: SurfaceHolder, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

}

override fun surfaceDestroyed(p0: SurfaceHolder) {
    if (playThread.isRunning) {
        playThread.isRunning = false
        var isCheck = true

        while (isCheck) {
            try {
                playThread.join()
                isCheck = false
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                Log.d("TAG", e.stackTrace.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error image]